# How to pronounce meijer

Tags: pronunciation

There is a supermarket called Meijer near my house, how do you pronounce 'Meijer'  ?  Does it sound like 'mire' ?

Comment: If they are near your house, have you thought about going there and asking them yourself? I don' t think they use shibboleths to determine who can enter the store.

Comment: This isn't really an English question. The name is of Dutch origin, and in Dutch sounds similar to Meyer. However, that doesn't mean the family pronounces it that way. Your best bet is to go to the store and find out how they say it, as Jim suggests.

Comment: This question is not about the English Language.

Comment: Actually it sounds like 'mire' according to what I heard from the broadcast in that market, but I don't know whether it was native and where did 'j' go in that pronunciation.

Comment: @booksee The j is a y sound. It's the glide between the two syllables of Meyer, or mire if you pronounce mire with two syllables (and identical to Meyer).

Comment: Meijer has a YouTube channel where they post their television advertisements: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0eFwA1lJzuLt24ZU4CBgwg

Comment: @ChrisPhan Great answer! I should have thought of resorting to their YouTube channel. Well, now it becomes clear to me that it sounds like 'my-yer', which is really close to 'mire'([maier]) with an emphasis on '[i]' in my view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do you pronounce 'Meijer' ?

*I* pronounce it like Meyer.

> Does it sound like 'mire' ?

I used to shop in a Meijer store and the pronunciation my ear heard is like *Meyer* rather than *mire*.  However, it's possible the ads, announcements, etc were using the latter pronunciation and that I wasn't hearing the difference.  In some accents the two pronunciations are not far apart.

Comment: I have also heard it called *Meyer*, which for some people is the same as *mire*.  To be clear, the store name is definitely pronounced so that there are two distinct syllables.  I say this as someone who has spent a lot of time in western Michigan, though I'm not from there.

Comment: I felt surprised once I heard 'mire' in the ad because I would pronounce it like 'major' or 'mayjer' instead of 'mire'. Anyway, next time I will ask some assistants in Meijer and see if they give me same answer.

Comment: @booksee _Major_ is definitely not likely to be the intended pronunciation. As others have said, it's a Dutch name, and in Dutch, the letter j is not pronounced as the j in _jew_ in English, but as the y in _yew_.